# Рифма к слову секс

Tags: рифма

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, подобрать рифму к слову секс. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Только  **кекс, рефлекс и бифштекс**.

Воспользуйтесь ресурсами "рифмы онлайн", их много в Интернете, например:

[Помощник поэта | stihi.ru](http://www.stihi.ru/cgi-bin/assist.pl)

Answer (score 1):

Ещё, *дополнительно*: **циркумфлекс, ромштекс, унисекс, "крекс, фекс, пекс"**  ( "Золотой ключик" ).

**Дополнение**
 Предлагаю найденный мною образчик ( не обессудьте, какой есть ):

Свободен от любовного выбора,
 Выбрать дружбу? Любовь? Или секс?
 И какая от этого была бы нам выгода.
 Ну как тебе, написанный мною текст?

*Елена Ульянова, "Каждый день, проводя с тобою"*

Answer (score 0):

Точные рифмы вы без труда найдёте на различных ресурсах, подбирающих рифмы. Из неточных интересной является *секс-текст*. Также рифму можно получить от слов, заканчивающихся на -ек (век, калек, грек и т. п.), если следующую строчку начать со звука *С*. Например:

> Наш с тобой вчерашний **секс**,
>   Как теченье быстрых **рек
>
>   С**то сверкающих комет,
>   Ну, и прочий винегрет.